# Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE - No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I have a `Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE` app.

with this test configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.bonansa")
@ComponentScan({"com.bonansa"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableMBeanExport(registration= RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING)
public class ApplicationTestConfig {
}
```

this application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

and this test

```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = ApplicationTestConfig.class)
    @MockBeans({ 
                @MockBean(UserService.class),
                // @MockBean(UserRepository.class)
            })
    public class AuthorisationControllerTest implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
        private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;
      
    
        @Before
        public void setup() {
            this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
        }
    
        @Test
        public void testA() throws Exception {
       }
    }
```

if I don't mock `UserRepository.class`, I got a `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available` and I don't understand because I am using a in memory DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nunyet, the problem is that although you are configuring H2 to store the information in memory, from the point of view of Spring and Spring Boot, you have the same database system, the same transactions, the same entities, ... in summary, the same behavior as if you were using H2 and storing the information on the filesystem or other different database system.

If you do not mock your repository, Spring will try to create the actual `UserRepository` and look forward the required dependencies to do so, like `entityManagerFactory` in your case.